# Querying jsonb array for partial value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

In a Rails 5.2 app, the `User` model has the `subscriptions` jsonb attribute

```
t.jsonb "subscriptions", default: [], null: false
```

An example is

```
irb(main):091:0> User.first.subscriptions
=> [{"id"=>"dfdaad60", "type"=>"Organization"}, 
    {"id"=>"18616f4d", "type"=>"Project"}]
```

How can I, using arel, get the `id`s of all the `subscriptions` having `type` equal `Project`?

I have tried to use the `@>` operator without success.

Answer (score 0):

Following will return array of `ids` for subscriptions(having type 'Project') of Users,

```
User.pluck(:subscriptions).flatten.map { |x| x['id'] if x['type'] == 'Project' }.compact
```

You do not need `where` AR or AREL query as you need only `ids` present inside subscriptions for type having 'Project' & can be get as above.

Comment: It is `[{ type: 'Project'}]` instead of `{ type: 'Project'}` I think, since it's an array of objects.

Comment: This is hardly scalable (picture a double map operation on a million users)

Comment: double map? He need to filter id from selected subscriptions also which have different 'type' So need to filter inside also.

Comment: Your pluck was a map before hence the double map. This is achievable through a single SQL query, I'll post an answer

Comment: @VincentRolea yup, I added pluck which can improve performance. But two filters are needed (pluck & map)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick, using a custom SQL statement:

```
sql = "SELECT value->'id' AS id FROM users, jsonb_array_elements(users.subscriptions) WHERE data @> '#{[{type: "Project"}].to_json}'"
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
puts result.to_a
```

Comment: I'd need ActiveRecord::Relation since the result needs to be chained with where clauses. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ActiveRecordExtended](https://github.com/GeorgeKaraszi/ActiveRecordExtended) gem to find all users which have a project type subscription:

```
User.where.contains(subscriptions: { type: "Project" })
```

I would then get ids in ruby.